What do the inscriptions in Pomposa abbey say?
I've recently visited  Pomposa Abbey, a Benedictine monastery in northern Italy near Ferrara, and while visiting I've stumbled upon these inscriptions below a fresco depicting an Hydra.
I have currently identified only a date (1463) and the following words:

"[...] de Modena" (a city in Italy)
"EAVSPERO" (can't find a translation, maybe it's some kind of medieval Latin)
"ESIPFEONE(?) DA ESTE" (the Este Family once was a noble family that ruled vast territories in northern and central Italy and parts of central Europe (e.g., Austria), which actually came in contact with the Abbey)
"[I?]MENAVA LIMANTIXI(?)" (got no idea for this one, but also seems like medieval Latin)

Any help is greatly appreciated in reconstructing and translating these inscriptions, whether they be phrases or just names, and if there's any notable names it would interesting to find any more information regarding them! If it helps, the Abbey itself has existed since the 9th century.
dunno if this is the right place to ask (if it isn't, please do tell me!)

Pomposa Abbey lists that as "L’Idra dalle 7 teste minaccia la Chiesa • The 7-headed Hydra Threatens the Church"

"Spero" is "I hope"  EAV might be EAU.

In 1463  Bertold II died ending the Marquisate of Este See: Modena Borso took over as the first Duke of Modena.

I believe this might actually be panel 53, La Bestia dalle sette teste e il Libro Divino • The 7-headed Beast and the Holy Book. ; the indistinct circles over the creatures' heads being the crowns of the Beast .

A YouTube video here shows the panel in relationship to the wall. The 'hydra' is visible on the left of the frame, 'the beast' in the center, matching the order in the publication cited above.

The House of Este did not exactly rule Austria. One Margrave of Este had both an Italian wife and a German wife.  The Italian Estes were descended from the Italian wife, and the Younger House of Guelf or Welf in Germany (and Great Britain) is descended from the German wife.  The younger Welf's ruled the Duchy of Bavaria on and off from 1070 to 1180.  By Austria do you mean the Empire of Austria (1804-1918), modern Austria since 1918, or the Margravaite, Duchy, & Archduchy of Austria?   Much of moder Austria once belonged the medieval Duchy of Bavaria.  Continued.

Continued.  The Duchy of Carnintha separated from Bavaria in 976. It including Carniola (now in Slovenia) whic was separated from Carinthia in 1140, and Styria which became a separate duchy in 1180).  So the Welfs never ruled Carinthia, Styria, or Carniola.    Tyrol & Voralberg were part of Bavaria while the Welfs ruled it & later became separate.  The Margravaite of Austria was part of the Duchy of Bavaria untril it became a separate duchy in 1156, so the Welfs were overlords of Austrai for a while. Burgenland was part of the KIngdom o fHungary until 1921.  Continued.

Continued.  So Burgenland was never ruled by the Welfs.  So only some parts of modern Austria were ever ruled by the Welfs.  The Empire of Austria included modern Austria, and the Kingdoms of Hungary, Croatia, Bohemia, Galicia & Lodomeria, and Lombardy Venetia, none of which were ever ruled by Welfs.  So the saying that the Welfs branch of the House of Este once ruled Austria is only partially correct.

@MCW thanks for the help! The date I've seen, 1463, may not be related to the Este inscription though: the guide herself told us that these were made by various people in different times, so the Este inscription may be older than that date or more recent. Also judging by how it's written, it may have probably not been the same person, but that's based on my personal judgement.

@MAGolding thanks for the correction! In school we didn't focus that much on the Este Family, and the guide told us that they did actually rule Austria without specifying which parts, so I mistakenly took that as at least the majority. I'm pretty sure the inscription is related to the Italian Estes, so I think we should focus more on that branch of the family. However, I see no names like the one I've read, "Esipfeone", in the family tree. Maybe I've read it wrong?
